# Clicking Keyboard Keys with Javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, click, mouse

Is it possible to click Keyboard keys with Javascript?

I want to click the Windows + M key. I will try it on the Chrome console. Is it possible to click the Windows + M key? Or can CTRL + left mouse click on a link?

Can you send a sample code? I need your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

The same behavior of "CTRL + left mouse click" can be achievied with code.
window.open(url, '_blank')

But if you are trying to control the browser you need another tool. Autohotkey or something similar.